# Issue in Maven Project: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-6, spring-annotations

**I'm having issue with the annotation @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy**

How can I solve this issue. I tried different approach but it's still not working

Here is the file ciconfig.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    
        <context:annotation-config />
    
        <!-- 
        <bean class="com.springcore.ci.Person" name="person">
            <constructor-arg value="Vaibhav More"></constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg value="25" type="int"></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
         -->
        <bean class="com.springcore.ci.Person" name="person">
            <property name="name" value="Vaibhav"></property>
            <property name="Id" value="25"></property>
        </bean>
        
        <bean class="com.springcore.ci.Person" name="p" init-method="start" destroy-method="end">
            <property name="name" value="Sachin Tendulkar"></property>
            <property name="Id" value="26"></property>
        </bean>
        
        <!-- Activity LifeCycle Init Destroy methods are used to two activity life cycles -->
        
    </beans>
```

And pom.xml file

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
      <groupId>com.springcore</groupId>
      <artifactId>springcore</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
      <name>springcore</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>
    
      <dependencies>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

It is showing me following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [com/springcore/ci/ciconfig.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 8; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

**How can I solve this annotation error.**
I have added dependencies but it's still not working.